# Win10 64-bit - Wallet not restored after upgrade to 0.11.0 Hydra GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows, 0.11.0.0

I've upgraded the wallet on my Win10 64-bit PC from 0.10.3.1. Beta 2 to the 0.11.0 Hydra release. It hung up at 3442 blocks to go for a long time, then finished the download.

However, the $XMR I had in my account went to zero, and $XMR I've tried to transfer in from my Bittrex account didn't arrive.

Any ideas how I can rectify this? Thanks! Do I have to just delete everything from my PC and start again, backing up using my private key?

Comment: Do you see any unauthorized transaction on the `History` page of the GUI? Or is it simply blank?

Comment: No transactions. The history page is blank.

Comment: First, exit the GUI. Subsequently, browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero` on Windows) and rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`. Lastly, restart the GUI. This triggers a wallet refresh from scratch, which should take at most 10-20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the support dEBRUYNE! I followed your instructions. History and account balance are still blank. Would installing the 0.11.0 wallet on a different computer resolve this if I use my 25-word key to link it?

Comment: Are you sure the address matches? Perhaps you accidentally opened another wallet? Restoring with the 25 word mnemonic seed will most likely resolve your issue. Note that you don't necessarily need to use a different computer for this. You can simply go to the `Settings` page of the GUI and press `Close wallet`. Subsequently, in the wizard, choose `Restore wallet from keys or mnemonic seed`.

Comment: I do have two wallets. The default one that I set up when I first downloaded back in July. I use the password for that to log in/log out. I'd moved XMR back-and-forth regularly without issues. Didn't hit this problem until 0.11.0.

Comment: The other wallet is something I created by mistake messing around on the GUI, but I never use the password for that one when I log in. Don't think I've accessed it since it was created.

Comment: Double check if you're using the right wallet. If you still have a problem thereafter, restore from seed (I posted instructions in a previous comment).

Comment: Not sure how it happened, but XMR was in what I thought was a dormant, unused wallet after I did a restore. Can't wrap my head around it since I hadn't logged in since it was created a few months ago. Thanks for the guidance. Really appreciated. 

Comment: Good to hear that you resolved your issue and you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Restored two wallets associated with the GUI on my PC. $XMR was in the second. Upgrade to 0.11.0 seemed to have defaulted a previously unused wallet.